Не удается авторизоваться через API Jira , хотя через Postman авторизоваться получается
Через Postman авторизоваться получается (ниже скриншот), а через программу нет (ниже код), получаю ошибку 401 (ниже скриншот). Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Public class RestClient {

private String server = "company.com";
private RestTemplate rest;
private HttpHeaders headers;
private HttpStatusCode status;

public RestClient() {

    this.rest = new RestTemplate();
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Accept", "*/*");
    //headers.add("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
    headers.add("Connection","keep-alive");


    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("user:password".getBytes()));
    System.out.println(basicAuth);

    headers.add("Authorization", basicAuth);

}

  public String get(String uri) {

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server + uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
    this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());

    System.out.println(requestEntity.getBody());
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}

Вот ошибка

POM XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pirp2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pirp2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.pirp2.PiroApp</start-class>

        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rcarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>



      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20240205</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


попробуйте так Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("user:password".getBytes()) либо так Base64.encodeBase64("user:password".getBytes())

Какая версия Spring?

@RomanC Добавил POM для наглядности. Спасибо за отзывчивость.

@DaniilLoban Здравствуйте! Спасибо за отклик.   Первый вариант не помог , ошибка идентичная.  А во втором варианте  такого метода не существует у меня  (encodeBase64) :(

@VaagnAkopyan Ещё добавь полный стэктрейс ошибки в текстовом виде.

@RomanC получилось несколько другим способом, описал ниже.

По итогу спустя неделю всяческих попыток и разбора документации Spring получилось следующим образом:
Создал метод, который возвращает RestClient:
 static   RestClient getSimpleRC(String uri){
        return    RestClient.builder()
                .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())

                .baseUrl("https://company.com/rest/api/2/issue/"+uri+"?field=status")

                .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("Authorization","Basic passwordinbase64="))
                .build();

    }



 RestClient restClient1= getSimpleRC(jirdID);

Вызов метода
    String status=restClient1.get()
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve().
            body(String.class);

